# Efficiency, Resources - store all data in one or multiple ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, split, resources

so this must have been asked before, but i could'nt find something useful, so sry.

Here is my scenario:
I want to store Information about Items, their price and other values in an ArrayList. Lets say we have about 10.000 items in the list when we're done. My question is, what way is the fastet / what takes less resources for the system so that the app runs most efficient.

Should i:
use one ArrayList for all the Data Like this

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("name;price;from");

String[] seperated = items.get(i).split(";");
seperated[0]...
```

and then have to split it whenever i need to read from it.
(will be each time a customer is searching an item, i could then only split the entries that fit the search criteria)

or should i use 3 ArrayLists with 10.000 Items each.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your spec, but if it were me, I would implement an `Item` object:

```
class Item {
    private String _id;
    private String _name;
    private String _price;
    private String _from;

    //getters,setters,etc.
}
```

Then have a `HashMap` to look up the `Item`s by id.

```
HashMap<String,Item> items = new HashMap<>();
```

You can get a list of all your items via:

```
items.values();
```

Or, you can perform an `O(1)` lookup via id:

```
items.get(someId);
```

Comment: i would go with that. Unfortunately i have no clue if it is possible.
Im extending from ArrayAdapter class to display the items in a ListView and have no clue how i should do that

Comment: Well, it is *possible*. I have implemented solutions like this in the past. The question is whether it fits your problem. Using `HashMaps` and objects this way are both efficient and easy on memory. So this solution fulfills both requirements, rather than sacrificing one for the other.

Answer (score 2):

Faster parsing - multiple arrays.
Less memory used - single array.

It depends on how large you expect the array(s) to become. A proper way would be to load only as many items as are needed. E.g. if on the screen you see 10 items, you load 30 and (un)load more as they are removed/requested.